# Results being returned in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a stored procedure that is run at the end of every day which will return the attendance percentage of each student in a class, the result set will show the students previous attendance percentage compared against their new percentage. But for some reason the results are being stored in multiple rows instead of one row. The diagrams below will give you a better understanding of the problem.

The Two Tables:

**Student Table**

[image]

**Percentage Table**

[image]

The code I have written to get the results into a combined table:

```
select 
StudentTb.StudentId,
StudentTb.Forename,
StudentTb.Surname,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0),103) as [Previous Reading Date]
case studentTb.Date 
when DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) then PercentageTb.Percentage
End
'Previous Percentage'
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0),103) as [Present Reading Date]
case studentTb.Date 
when DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) then PercentageTb.Percentage
End
'Current Percentage'
from studentTb inner join
                  PercentageTb on studentTb.StudentID = PercentageTb.StudentID
```

and this is the result set from this query!

[image]

However this is not the way I intended the results to look, below shows the desired result set!

[image]

[image]

I thought the `CASE` statement would have done that for me but obviously I was wrong, could someone please give me some indication on where I need to go from here?

Comment: the desired result set has been inserted twice by mistake!

Comment: Is it just me or there are MANY syntax mistakes...?

Comment: Your join is the problem. You need more logic to break it out. The join is matching 2 rows for each student (ie. 2*2=4)

Comment: Well that is correct right? 2 for each day = 2*2 = 4

Comment: Oh nevermind, i misunderstood the wanted result

Comment: no because the previous day if i read the expected result correct goes into the same row but the column called 'Previous result'. Needs to add grouping claus for student and a case statement for the two results columns

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish what you want that should work is to use the `max()` aggregate function to flatten the results like this:

```
select 
    s.StudentID,
    s.Forename,
    s.Surname,
    max(case when p.date = CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0),103) then p.date end) prev_date,
    max(case when p.date = CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0),103) then p.percentage end) prev_perc,
    max(case when p.date = CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0),103) then p.date end) curr_date,
    max(case when p.date = CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0),103) then p.percentage end) curr_perc
from studentTb s
inner join percentageTb p on s.StudentID = p.StudentID
group by s.StudentID, s.Forename, s.Surname
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89e83/2)

Another option would be to join the `percentageTb` table twice (once for the current date and once for the previous day), see [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89e83/5).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do a select with sub select? Assuming a student can only have one result on each day

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE
DECLARE @PreviousDate DATE
SET @CurrentDate = 
SET @PreviousDate = 


SELECT
    StudentTb.StudentId AS [ID],
    StudentTb.Forename AS [Forename],
    StudentTb.Surname AS [Surname],
    (SELECT Percentage from PercentageTb where StudentID = S.studentID and Date = @PreviousDate) AS [PreviousPercentage]
    (SELECT Percentage from PercentageTb where StudentID = S.studentID and Date = @CurrentDate) AS [CurrentPercentage]
from studentTb  AS S
```